# Load CSV using the headers SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am looking for a good generic SP in SQL server to load CSV files using the header row to create the necessary table columns for the temp table.

For example, I have a table with 20 columns in it, and I have been told to load a csv file into SQL server I have to load all the columns into the table.  So, that means I have to go in and create all this by hand and then load the data.  Think that is a time waster.

So, I was wondering if there was a way to read the header row use it to create the columns, whether my table has 10 or 20 and the use bulk update to load the data itself.

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm sure you can do this if every column is a text type. How will you handle numerics, or dates? How will you determine appropriate column widths? I can see a number of problems.

Comment: I could see doing it as VB code, you load only the first column into a temp table (#headers).  Then you would read the next line and run the len function, that would get your your field widths and that would go in column 2 of #headers, then you would have to figure an easy way to determine data type, that would go into column 3 of #header.

Then use that table to create the Bulk Insert command?